# Debug Routes with Navigate/Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In a previous question I said [I was following this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRaelG7v0OU), it should be an easy one.

But the tutorial might be quite old, it uses `Switch` and `Redirect`. I am trying to use it with the new `Routes` and `Navigate`... but it displays a blank screen by just renaming them.

So I have searched about **debugging routes** but I cannot make the answers to work. Of course, I might be missing something and possibly even trivial here.

Since I am learning React, I almost copy verbatim, with very few cosmetic touches:

```
import React from "react"
import TextEditor from "./TextEditor"
import { 
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom"
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid"

class DebugRouter extends BrowserRouter {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      console.log('initial history is: ', JSON.stringify(this.history, null,2))
      this.history.listen((location, action)=>{
          console.log(
              `The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`
          )
          console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`, JSON.stringify(this.history, null,2));
      });
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <DebugRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Navigate to={`/documents/${uuidV4()}`} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/documents/:id">
          <TextEditor />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </DebugRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now I get three errors, but they are all the same, and I don't know why it throws three times in the same line...

`TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` in `_classCallCheck`

The line is:

```
export default function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
}
```

I am not even remotely skilled in react to understand why it goes berserk, when using the `DebugRouter` I found in another question on how to debug. The culprit, says the log, is here:

```
DebugRouter
src/App.js:12
   9 | import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid"
  10 | 
  11 | class DebugRouter extends BrowserRouter {
> 12 |   constructor(props){
  13 |       super(props);
  14 |       console.log('initial history is: ', JSON.stringify(this.history, null,2))
  15 |       this.history.listen((location, action)=>{
```

If you need to know what happens exactly when I use the `BrowserRouter`, [the blank page HTML is here](https://pastebin.com/qTmXC4ev). Nothing fancy, it seems that the routes do not work at all.

Am I missing something in upgrading the tutorial to a more up-to-date react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BrowserRouter` isn't a React, or even Javascript, Class component, so it can't be extended, it's a React function component. From what I see here it seems you just want to "spy" on the `location` object when routes change.

Create a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#layout-routes) component that uses the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) and [`useNavigationType`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation-type) hooks and a `useEffect` hook to "listen"  for location changes and log out the details.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useLocation, useNavigationType } from 'react-router-dom';

const DebugLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigationType = useNavigationType(); // "POP" | "PUSH" | "REPLACE"

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("The current URL is", {...location});
    console.log("The last navigation action was", navigationType);
  }, [location, navigationType]);

  return <Outlet />;
};

export default DebugLayout;
```

Import and render `DebugLayout` as a layout route. Also FYI, the routed components should be passed to each `Route` component's `element` prop. Only other `Route` components are valid children in the case of nesting routes.

```
...
import DebugLayout from '../path/to/DebugLayout';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<DebugLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={`/documents/${uuidV4()}`} />} />
          <Route path="/documents/:id" element={<TextEditor />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved! Might I ask why I was getting an empty page before trying the debugging of `Route`? I cannot find any sensible reason in my very beginner's mind.

Comment: @senseiwa From what I could tell that was likely caused by rendering the content as children of the `Route` when they should be passed on the `element` prop.

Comment: Thank you, the tutorial must be really outdated.

Comment: @senseiwa Yeah, considering `react-router-dom@6` has been out for almost a year now.